# Free allocated memory in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, free

Let's say I have allocated a big enough `char**` array.

Why can I do `free(arr)` but not `free(arr + 5)`?

Please notice that I'm not speaking about `arr[0]` or `arr[5]`.

Comment: Mainly because the standard says so. For a more technical reasons, some `malloc()` implementations put bookkeeping data right before the allocated memory region. Passing something else than the pointer `malloc()` gave you to `free()` would cause `free()` to interpret garbage data as its bookkeeping data with fatal consequences.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`malloc(3)` doesn't work that way. It allocates a fixed-size block of data in the memory, adds metadata at the start of the block (like the address of the next free block or the size of the block) and returns the address just after the metadata.

[image: Malloc]

`free(3)` needs the information contained in the metadata to be executed (for example, to update the addresses of the free blocks in its linked list. If you provide a pointer that has not been allocated by `malloc(3)`, the metadata are not present and `free` is unable to do that.

For that reason, the man page of `free(3)` explicitely forbids to pass a pointer that has not been allocated by `malloc(3)

> The `free()` function frees the memory space pointed to  by `ptr`,
>   which  must  have been returned by a previous call to `malloc()`,
>   `calloc()`, or `realloc()`.  Otherwise, or if `free(ptr)` has already
>   been called before, undefined behavior occurs.  If `ptr` is `NULL`,
>   no operation is performed.

Doing so may result in **undefined behavior**, that, if your system has not put some protections in place to prevent you from doing so, could result in security breaches, since `free(3)` will **write** on arbitrary memory zones pointed by the fake metadata.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now.

Comment: Then please mark the answer that solved your problem!

Answer (score 2):

You always call `free()` with the pointer that was returned by `malloc()`, `realloc()` or `calloc()`. You must not pass any other pointers.

From the [`free()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) manual:

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which 
>   must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc(), or
>          realloc().  Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called
>          before, undefined behavior occurs.  If ptr is NULL, no operation is
>           performed.

Comment: Shouldn't as in “must not.”

Comment: Thank you, I get it now.

Comment: @FUZxxl Indeed. Thanks.